# Computing $a ^ {^nC_r}$ % prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, computational-mathematics

We need to find $a^{n \choose r} \% M$ where $M$ is prime number.
Problem is ${n \choose r}$ can be really large to store in integer data type (or long long in c++) so i need to calculate ${n \choose r}\%M$ which i know how to do. I also know how to compute $a^b$ in $O(log  b)$ time complexity using exponentiation technique.

I am guessing (failed to prove) : 
$a^{n \choose r} \% M = a^{{n \choose r}\%M}\%M$. (?)
 
It looks good on small numbers but can't really prove or disprove it.
Can anybody confirm if its true, if it isn't any alternative to compute my original expression?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem or  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem might help

Comment: You have to compute $\binom nr$ modulo  $M-1$.

Comment: @FabioLucchini why? i smell fermat.. so what you are saying is in the equation i have written, i need to replace ${n \choose r}\%M-1$ that is it?

Comment: @ZooOoz yes. It follows from Fermat's little theorem. Exception being when $M$ divides $a$

Comment: @Adam can you tell how it follows? Fermat's Little theorem connects exponent to prime mod here M. but my exponent , ${n \choose r}$ is unrelated to M.. so i can't see the implication?

Comment: Also, in fermat, modulo M remains same, but here @FabioLucchini is saying $\% M-1$ !

Comment: @ZooOoz It's better to explain this with an exercise. For example, we want to calculate $9^{2000} \,\text{mod}\, 5$. Then $9^{2000} = 9^4 \cdot 9^{1996}$. We can continue this, as long as the exponent is $\geq4$. Fermat's theorem tells us that $9^4 \,\text{mod}\, 5 = 1$. Now, $9^{2000} = (9^4)^k \cdot 9^{2000 \,\text{mod}\, 4}$. Now by the Fermat's theorem, $ (9^4)^k \cdot 9^{2000 \,\text{mod}\, 4} \,\text{mod}\, 5 = 9^{2000 \,\text{mod}\, 4} \,\text{mod}\, 5 $. The same arguments works for any prime $M$, as long as $M$ doesn't divide our $a$

Comment: @Adam Thanks a lot! I understood it from you. Its sad that i dont have enough reputation to upvote you :/

Comment: Same question asked 2 days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850501/congruences-for-big-numbers